# Solr 3.6.2 on Tomcat 7: .doc files are only being accepted after resaving them with OpenOffice?

Tags: solr

I have a large set of files which I am trying to index and there were no problems with file formats such as pdf or html. But as soon as I am adding a .doc file via post.jar, Error 400 (Bad Requests) appears.

After resaving them, the files are committed just fine. I could not find any log files (even though I activated logging). Are there any problems with the following schema?

```
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="title" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="subject" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="description" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="comments" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="keywords" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="text" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="sku" type="text_de_splitting_tight" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="payloads" type="payloads" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved: There was a non-multiValued field called "company" which has been used in the original .doc files.